# Display Record from sql server 2008 in Textbox in vb.net 2010 does not work

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
    conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=JOODAY-PC;Initial Catalog=dblogin;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    conn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblRiceAllocationPassbook WHERE [Month] = '%" & ComboBox1.Text & "%' and [Year]  = '%" & txtyear.Text & "%'", conn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    txtmonthlyallocation.Text = dt.Rows(0)("[IBSP Weekly Allocation]").ToString
    conn.Close()
```

above is my code for displaying the value of the column "IBSP Weekly Allocation" in the txtmonthlyallocation textbox. What is wrong with this code and why does it not work? Thanks.

Comment: Please give more details about what "does not work". Please read this as well http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Option using a DataReader to find something and show a field associated with the found row

```
Dim searchValue As String = "BE-2349"

Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ConnectionString}
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With
        {
            .Connection = cn,
            .CommandText = "SELECT ProductID, Name, ProductNumber FROM Production.Product WHERE ProductNumber = @ProductNumber"}
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNumber", searchValue)

        cn.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        reader.Read()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            TextBox1.Text = reader.GetSqlString(1)
        End If

    End Using
End Using
```

With xml literals for command text

```
Dim searchValue As String = "BE-2349"

Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = My.Settings.ConnectionString}
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With
        {
            .Connection = cn,
            .CommandText =
            <SQL>
                SELECT 
                    ProductID, 
                    Name, 
                    ProductNumber 
                FROM Production.Product 
                WHERE ProductNumber = @ProductNumber
            </SQL>.Value}
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNumber", searchValue)

        cn.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        reader.Read()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            TextBox1.Text = reader.GetSqlString(1)
        End If

    End Using
End Using
```